# How to use shell to convert HTML to table

Tags: shell-script, html

I have hundreds of HTML files that are relatively simple in content and maintain a consistent format.

I need to convert them to tables, can I use a shell script to do this?

**HTML source code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="text-1">Text 1</p>
        <p class="text-2">Text 2</p>
        <p class="text-3">Text 3</p>
        <p class="text-4">Text 4</p>
        <p class="text-5">Text 5</p>
        <p class="text-6">Text 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="text-1">Text 1</p>
        <p class="text-2">Text 2</p>
        <p class="text-3">Text 3</p>
        <p class="text-4">Text 4</p>
        <p class="text-5">Text 5</p>
        <p class="text-6">Text 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="text-1">Text 1</p>
        <p class="text-2">Text 2</p>
        <p class="text-3">Text 3</p>
        <p class="text-4">Text 4</p>
        <p class="text-5">Text 5</p>
        <p class="text-6">Text 6</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Converted table source code**

```
<table>
    <caption>Page Title</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is the mind map.**

[image]

Before asking the question, I tried to look up information on the Internet and found that I could extract the HTML content using the [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) tool, which is used as follows.

```
# Extracting page titles
cat demo.html | pup 'body > h1 text{}'

# Extracting paragraph text
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-1 text{}'
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-2 text{}'
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-3 text{}'
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-4 text{}'
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-5 text{}'
cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-6 text{}'
```

In the next I ran into difficulty, I didn't know how to make it into a shell script. It involves shell loops and I spent a few days trying to figure it out, but without success.

Can you all help me? Thank you in advance!

**Update**

This is what I have tried to do. It has several problems.

- It can only handle one `<div class="row">...</div>` data, which is the trickiest problem I've
  encountered (The problem is shown below). It involves the shell loop problem.
  [image]
- It can only convert one HTML file at a time, and ideally works in
  batches of hundreds of HTML files (exported to another directory and
  saved, file names remain consistent).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Extracts HTML content
page_title=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > h1 text{}')
paragraph_text_a=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-1 text{}')
paragraph_text_b=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-2 text{}')
paragraph_text_c=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-3 text{}')
paragraph_text_d=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-4 text{}')
paragraph_text_e=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-5 text{}')
paragraph_text_f=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body > div.row > p.text-6 text{}')

# Print the contents in a predetermined format
cat << EOF
<table>
    <caption>$page_title</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$paragraph_text_a</td>
            <td>$paragraph_text_b</td>
            <td>$paragraph_text_c</td>
            <td>$paragraph_text_d</td>
            <td>$paragraph_text_e</td>
            <td>$paragraph_text_f</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
EOF
```

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to do this with a shell-script unless you can find a tool that specifically parses HTML in some useful way. I would use whichever scripting language or programming language I was comfortable with and make use of it's HTML-parsing libraries. (In my case, Perl and Go would be good candidates but your mileage will vary). If your data is absolutely 100% uniform you could maybe use a tool like `sed` even though it is dangerous to do so.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Indeed, I saw the same point on the web. But I have no programming experience and it would become difficult to make minor adjustments to this. Similarly, shell scripts run on the server and do not require a runtime environment to be installed.

Comment: Although my script below works in most cases, if you really want to avoid edge-cases you'll have to install the HTML::Element perl module and use a script based on this. The code will be safer and more readable. I didn't use it because now you only need perl (which is most likely already installed on your system)

Comment: @Garo Thank you! Can it be implemented using a shell script? I've updated the question to add what I've tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extract cell by cell, which will make it harder for you to rebuilt the table.

Using simple `bash` and `pup` only:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(grep '<div ' demo.html | wc -l)
page_title=$(cat demo.html | pup 'body h1 text{}')

tbody() {
    for ((i=1;i<count+1;++i)); do
        IFS=, row=$(cat demo.html | pup "body div.row:nth-of-type($i) text{}" | grep '\S' | paste -s -d, -)
        printf "\t\t<tr>\n"
        printf '\t\t\t<td>%s</td>\n' $row
        printf "\t\t</tr>\n"
    done
}

cat <<EOF
<table>
    <caption>$page_title</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
`tbody`
    </tbody>
</table>
EOF
```

**Output**

```
<table>
    <caption>Page Title</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
            <th>Hard Coded</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text 1</td>
            <td>Text 2</td>
            <td>Text 3</td>
            <td>Text 4</td>
            <td>Text 5</td>
            <td>Text 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**Explanation**

The idea is extract data row by row, by iterating until the last row. This snippet will give you the rows count:

```
grep '<div ' demo.html | wc -l
```

Then by using `nth-of-type(n)` as the selector, you can grab the whole row instead of column. You need to pass it to `grep '\S'` to get rid of blank lines. Then by passing to `paste -s -d, -`, will produce comma separated result.

```
IFS=, row=$(cat demo.html | pup "body div.row:nth-of-type($i) text{}" | grep '\S' | paste -s -d, -)
```

The `printf '\t\t\t<td>%s</td>\n' $row` will be expanded to `printf '\t\t\t<td>%s</td>\n' 'Text 1' 'Text 2' ...` and it will wrap each of the args with `<td>...</td>`

You can totally drop the `\t` part, it will just print indented result.

Answer (score 2):

The following should more or less do it, keep in mind that I :

- Only wrote it, I didn't test it. **Edit: Now i did test it, fixed some bugs, and it seems to work.**
- Am ignoring edgecases (multiple `<h1>`'s, `<tbody>` inside a tablefield and so on, ...)

Put it in "scriptname.pl", change the filenames on line 2 and 3 and run it with `perl scriptname.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open my $ifh, "inputfilename.html";
open my $ofh, ">outputfilename.html";
while(<$ifh>) {
  if(/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/) {
    my $header = << "END";
  <table>
    <caption>$1</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
            <th>Hard Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
END
    print $ofh $header;
  } elsif(/<div class="row">/) {
    print $ofh "<tr>\n";
  } elsif(/<\/div>/) {
    print $ofh "</tr>\n";
  } elsif(/<p class=".*?">(.*)<\/p>/) {
    print $ofh "<td>$1</td>\n";
  } elsif(/<\/body>/) {
    print $ofh "</tbody>\n</table>\n</body>\n";
  } else {
    print $ofh $_;
  }
}
close $ofh;
close $ifh;
```

Comment: Thank you! It tests valid.
Is it possible to implement it using a shell script? Use [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to select the HTML content. This allows me to make some minor adjustments and be more flexible.